# Change response body 404 in Loppback

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I'm new to loopback. I'm trying override response body when model record not found.

this is the default response body from explorer:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 404,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "could not find a model with id 666",
    "code": "MODEL_NOT_FOUND",
    "stack": "..."
  }
}
```

my expected result:

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "message": "could not find a model with id 666"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-middleware.html#middleware-phases

> final - Deal with errors and requests for unknown URLs.

```
  app.middleware('final', function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err && err.code === 'MODEL_NOT_FOUND') {
      res.statusCode = 404;
      res.json({status: 404, message: err.message});
    }else {
      next();
    }
  });
```

Register the with a file in the `boot` directory, in a file pointed to by `middleware.json`, or in `server.js`.

Comment: You save my life